# How to use script/program(like java) to compile/run cobol by invoke the compile/run command of cobol?

Tags: automated-tests, cobol, headless

We are using RDI (IBM Rational Developer for System i) to do cobol development work, we are eager to write automation test cases for our program, to make the testing work easier. But we don't know how to use script to compile and run cobol, which on i-series server.

For now, our solution is that we use scripts prepare test data (insert data to database/files),and then run cobol on RDI manually, finally, run scripts to check the results. It makes our work easier, but still not real automation test.

So, I want to know if there are some methods to invoke the compile&run process according to scripts, such eclipse headless or telnet technologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've already found the solution: use telnet to compile/run program. Because green screen is one kind of telnet, it reliable.